# Showing $P_n = {F_n \over {2^n}}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, fibonacci-numbers

Let $P_n$ be the probability that, if you flip a fair coin $n$ times, there are no consecutive heads. Also, let $F_n$ be the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, normalized by $F_1 = 1$ and $F_2 = 2$ and $F_n = F_{n−1} + F_{n−2}$ for $n \ge 3$.

Show that $P_n = {F_n\over {2^n}},\forall n \gt 0$

I'm not really sure where to get started on this question. I was thinking about finding an expression for $P_n$ in terms of $P_{n-1}$ and $P_{n-2}$ with boundary conditions but I am not exactly sure.

Comment: The general idea is good. However, I would rather let $a_n$ be the **number** of strings of length $n$ made up of H and/or T with no consecutive H. Establish the recurrence $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$.

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but this doesn't seem to work for $n=2$.

Comment: Split things into $P_n=H_n+T_n$ where $H_n$ denotes the probability of no consecutive heads in $n$ flips and the last flip being head and $T_n$ denotes the probability of no consecutive heads in $n$ flips and the last flip being tails. Then $H_{n+1}=\frac12T_n$ and $T_{n+1}=\frac12H_n+\frac12T_n$ while $P_{n+1}=H_{n+1}+T_{n+1}$. From there the induction on $(P_n)$ is direct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

There are two kinds of of sequences which have no two consecutive heads:

1. Sequences that start with a tail
2. Sequences that start with a head followed by a tail.